# Bash : how to grep string from file

Tags: linux, bash

am having issue with grep as VESTACP is using it a lot.

i have file mysql.conf

```
HOST='localhost' USER='root' PASSWORD='xxxxxx' CHARSETS='UTF8,LATIN1,WIN1250,WIN1251,WIN1252,WIN1256,WIN1258,KOI8' MAX_DB='500' U_SYS_USERS='' U_DB_BASES='1' SUSPENDED='no' TIME='05:32:47' DATE='2016-03-20'
```

now when i run

```
 echo host_str=$(grep "HOST='$1'" $VESTA/conf/mysql.conf)
```

i get empty result , although there is HOST in mysql.conf file which i pasted above in code

so any idea whats wrong with it

**UPDATE ::**  Vesta db connect code block

```
host_str=$(grep "HOST='$1'" $VESTA/conf/mysql.conf)
eval $host_str
if [ -z $HOST ] || [ -z $USER ] || [ -z $PASSWORD ]; then
    echo "Error: mysql config parsing failed"
    log_event "$E_PARSING" "$EVENT"
    exit $E_PARSING
fi
```

and i get

> Error: mysql config parsing failed

Comment: Are you running this in a script? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Can you print `$1` and check the value?

Comment: echo $1   empty ................

Comment: Well if `$1` is empty then you are effectively running `grep "HOST=''" $VESTA/conf/mysql.conf` command

Comment: thats strange $1 should contain localhost . as you can see in file its localhost

Comment: `$1` is the first argument of a script. Try giving "localhost" as argument of your script.

Comment: This is getting odder by the minute. The code snippet you show prints the error completely unrelated to your original question. What has the grep to do with the `if` testing the shell variables $HOST, $USER and $PORT?

Comment: @Harald The result of `grep` is passed to `eval` to set the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is the first parameter of your script.

So, `host_str=$(grep "HOST='$1'" $VESTA/conf/mysql.conf)` gets the line containing some variables from your file according to your parameter, and `eval $host_str` sets these variables in your script.

Therefore, your script needs an argument to know which host to look for in your file, in your case, it's localhost, so run: `./yourscript.sh localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `$1`. Rather try this:

```
echo host_str=$(grep -o "HOST='[^']*'" $VESTA/conf/mysql.conf)
```

The `[^']*` expands to everything that happens to be in between the single quotes. The option `-o` makes sure you only get the matching string, not the whole line, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Aaron: Que?  The only version of `grep` that doesn't consider the pattern as a regex is `fgrep`, aka `grep -F` these days.  Adding `-E` makes `grep` run in `egrep` mode — with extended regular expressions instead of basic regular expressions.

Comment: vestacp need $1 for further operations

Comment: Well, but if you keep `$1` in the pattern and if it does not expand exactly to what is in the file, your match result will stay empty.